# Is there a way to add the latest Activity History to an issues list when pulling all issues from Jira using Python?

Tags: python, rest, jira, issue-tracking

I'm pulling all of the issues from my project in Jira and pulling specific information from their corresponding fields. I've added them to a list and subsequently a dictionary. I'm missing the ability to pull the latest Activity History for each issue in order to be able to append to each one.

I've looked through the API documentation and cannot find a way to target the latest Activity History (or any for that matter). Using issues.field.worklogs does not work either.

```
import jira
from jira import JIRA
from openpyxl import Workbook
import pandas as pd

jira = JIRA(basic_auth=('user', 'pw'), options={'server': 'https://jira-website.com'})

issues = pd.DataFrame([])

block_size = 10
block_num = 0
allissues = []
while True:
 start_idx = block_num*block_size
 issues = jira.search_issues('project=MYPROJECT', start_idx, block_size)
 if len(issues) == 0:
    # Retrieve issues until there are no more to come
    break
 block_num += 1
 for issue in issues:
    #log.info('%s: %s' % (issue.key, issue.fields.summary))
    allissues.append(issue)

print('Number of issues:', len(allissues))
jiraExport = pd.DataFrame([])
for issue in allissues:
    d = {
    'key': issue.key,
    'assignee': issue.fields.assignee,
    'creator': issue.fields.creator.name,
    'reporter': issue.fields.reporter.name,
    'created': issue.fields.created,
    'description': issue.fields.description,
    'summary': issue.fields.summary,
    'issuetype': issue.fields.issuetype.name,
    'priority': issue.fields.priority,
    'status': issue.fields.status.name,
    'updated': issue.fields.updated,
    'original estimate': issue.fields.timeoriginalestimate,
    'component': issue.fields.components,
    'watchers': issue.fields.watches,    
    }
    jiraExport = jiraExport.append(d, ignore_index=True)

print(jiraExport)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make another call for each issue I think using
client.jira(issue_key) and with expand=changelog or some such to retrieve the history
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.6.1/#api/2/issue
Also see https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Is-it-possible-to-get-the-issue-history-using-the-REST-API/qaq-p/510094